# Java Equals on configurable number of fields for a third part class

Tags: java

I have to implement a method to test object equality as follows

```
isEqual(MyClass o1, MyClass o2, List<String> fieldNames)
```

Here `List<String> fieldNames` are the instance variables of `MyClass` which should be considered for equality.

`isEqual` method will be called from different code paths with different set of "`fieldNames`".

I looked at Apache EqualsBuilder but it doesn't provide a similar capability which I am looking for.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try `MyClass.class.getDeclaredFields()`

This will get you a list of all fields in a class. You can use `field.getName()` to get its `String`-name.

Next in your `isEqual()` you can use `MyClass.class.getField(fieldName)` to get the field. With `field.get(myClass)` you can get the value of this field of a certain instance.

Though instead of passing fieldNames, I would just pass `Field[]`. This skips the converting of `Field` to `String` and back to `Field`.

In case you want to learn more about this, take a look at [`Reflection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) from Java.

Good luck!

**Example**

```
boolean isEqual(MyClass obj1, MyClass obj2, Field[] fields) {
    for(Field field : fields)
        if(!field.get(obj1).equals(field.get(obj2)))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Calling it:

```
Class cls = MyClass.class;
isEqual(obj1, obj2, { cls.get("myField"), cls.get("anotherField") });
```

Comment: this would work but you don't expose the performance issues this would lead to; besides there is no method 'get' of Class; you mean getField

Comment: Well, this seems to be the case OP asks for. I suspect he wants to generate the list of fields based on UI. This would mean writing custom `Comparator`s without Reflection won't be possible.

Comment: Either case, OP will need to seriously consider consequences.

Comment: I really don't think there can be a scenario for comparing any fields, no matter if in UI or not. So Comparators would work

Comment: Lets say MyClass has 15 fields and I am exposing MyClass to other developers to provide data to my code. They can utilize any number of fields to send me data. And I need to find out if the recent data send by them is different than what they sent the last time.  That is why I was thinking of getting a List of fields from them and using these fields to compare cur and prev instances of MyClass.   The alternative to this can be asking each one of them to write their custom comparator for MyClass

Comment: You could run some tests on the overhead being caused. Though it depends on your app whether or not this could become an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have predefined 'sets' of fields (cases) for comparisons, you'll have to use Reflection. However this will lead to great overhead, especially if this operation is about to be performed often.

However, if you do have certain comparison scenarios, I would recommend creating custom comparator for each case.

For instance:

```
public interface MyComparator {
    boolean areEqual(MyClass class1, MyClass class2);
}
```

and some scenario implementation:

```
public class MyNamesComparator implements MyComparator {
    public boolean areEqual(MyClass class1, MyClass class2) {
        return class1.getNames().equals(class2.getNames());
    }
}
```

and in your business logic class:

```
public boolean areEqual(MyClass class1, MyClass class2, Class<? extends MyComparator> comparatorClass) {
   return comparatorClass.newInstance().areEqual(class1, class2);
}
```

and so on for whatever scenario you wish. I actually am pretty sure that you wouldn't need **any** comparators, so this approach will do for you.